# How to pass a complex structure between C and Java with JNI on Android NDK

Tags: java, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, share

I have a complex strucutre in the C code on my Android application and I would like to use it in the Java side.
I've done some research with google and in stackoverflow, so I've created the java class from my C strucutre, but now how to get it in Java.

I've found these informations, about making a pointer in the class and use this on the C side :

```
Get the field ID : (*env)->GetFieldID(...)
Get the pointer : (*env)->GetLongField(...)
Set the pointer : (*env)->SetLongField(...)
```

But I don't understand how it really works ...

Above, you can find what I've done until now ... not so much !
On the C side :

```
ComplexStructure Java_com_main_MainActivity_listenUDP(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{
    int i,taille;
    ComplexStructure myStruct;    
    taille = -1;    
    taille = recvfrom(socket, &myStruct, sizeof(ComplexStructure ), 0, &rcvAddr, &sizeOfSock);
    if(taille != -1)
    {   
        return myStruct;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And on the Java side :

```
public void getFromUDP() {

    ComplexClass myClass = new ComplexClass();
    myClass = listenUDP();              
}

@Override
public void run() {
    initUDP();
    getFromUDP();
}


public static native ComplexClass listenUDP();
public static native void initUDP();
public static native void closeUDP();

/** Load jni .so on initialization */
static {
     System.loadLibrary("native-interface");
}
```

EDIT : I want to add that my structure is very complex like that :

```
typedef struct{
  TYPE_A myStructA;
  TYPE_B myStructB;
  TYPE_C myStructC;
  TYPE_D myStructD;
}ComplexStructure;

typedef struct{
  float rad;
  int size;
  bool isEmpty;
}TYPE_A;

typedef struct{
  float rad;
  bool isEmpty;
  float color;
  int temp;
}TYPE_B;

typedef struct{
  int temp;
  float rain;
  bool isEmpty;
}TYPE_C;

typedef struct{
  float rad;
  int idPerson;
  bool isOnTime;
}TYPE_D;
```

Even more complex, just an example to show you how it is !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot pass raw C structs into Java and expect it to treat these structs as classes. You need to create a class for your struct. I see you already did that, so the only thing you need to do is to convert this struct into an instance of the class.

The code on the Java side:

```
public static native ComplexClass listenUDP();
```

will translate to:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_main_MainActivity_listenUDP(JNIEnv *env, jclass);
```

In that C code, you need to load the ComplexClass using the `env->FindClass();` function. Then to create a new instance of that class (it simplifies matters if you have zero-parameter constructor), you need to load a constructor method signature and "invoke" it in the `env->NewObject()` method. Full code:

```
jclass complexClass = env->FindClass("/com/main/ComplexClass");
jmethod constructor = env->GetMethodId(complexClass, "<init>", "()com/main/ComplexClass"); //The name of constructor method is "<init>"
jobject instance = env->NewObject(complexClass, constructor);
```

Then you need to set the fields of this class using `env->setXXXField();`. If you have more objects as fields and want to alse create them, then repeat the above process for another object.

This looks very complicated, but that's the price for using native C in managed Java code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer, it's very helpfull. As you say, it's very complicated, I thought it was possible to copy the structure to the class easly, but it's not ... Because my structure has lots of object/fields,so if I have to manualy add all the parameters, I will pass days on it. So, is it simpliest to receive directly in Java the UDP packet from my C application ?? Thank you so much @Jakub Zaverka

Comment: @Martin Take a look at the Datagrams: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html

Comment: Yes I know how to use DatagramSocket et DatagramPacket, but I don't know how to get my datas back :), for a String it's quite simple, but for a structure ...

Comment: `NewObject()` will return a local reference, which will go out of scope and become invalid when the creating stack frame, that is the native method, returns. Is there any risk that the new object gets garbage collected before a new reference to it is created on the Java side? For example, consider the Java code `ComplexClass cplxCls = listenUDP();` and the native (pseudo-)code `listenUDP() { return env->NewObject(complexClass, ctor) }`. Is `cplxCls` guaranteed to reference the object created by `NewObject(complexClass, ctor)`?