# passing structure from java to C code and vice versa using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to pass a structure from java to C code and return a structure from C to Java code using JNI. I haven't find something useful regarding structures and JNI on net.

Can someone please provide a simple code snippet for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a complex structure between C and Java with JNI on Android NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300039/how-to-pass-a-complex-structure-between-c-and-java-with-jni-on-android-ndk)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad area and you need to do more research online ( it's ell covered out there ).  However, briefly ...

If you simply want to keep a blob of data and pass it between java methods without changing it you can store it in a Java byte array.

You could also malloc() the struct on the C side and then pass Java a pointer ( stored ideally in a byte array for reasons I won;t go into ).  Again, Java can't mess with the data, but can at least pass a reference to it around.

If you actually need a data structure on both sides that you can access by fields and change, then you need to create wrapper functions that convert between the two ( C struct and Java class ).  One way to automate this is to use [SWIG](http://swig.org/) , which is a code generator that can generate JNI wrapper code for you from C include files.